# Unable to create a working jar for my application using NetBeans

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I have a small Java application which uses a SqLite database. I'm trying to build an executable jar from NetBeans. The application runs fine when I launch it from NetBeans but there is an error when I run the jar file produced by NetBeans in the dist folder. My application logs the following error:

```
GRAVE: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

In NetBeans there is a jar file for sqLite in Librairies but there is not lib folder in the dist folder. The sqLite jar is inside the jar produced by NetBeans. Here is the content of the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_45-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: ca.csf.dfc.poo.view.FenetrePrincipale
```

If you have any idea on how to deploy this application in a working jar using NetBeans, please help me. Thank you

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: One way that worked for me is to go to JRE System Library -> right clik -> build path -> configure build path -> add external jars -> select the jar and compile

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question...